# Gradle not picking up gradle.properties entry in init script

Tags: gradle

I'm trying to access a property that's set in ~/.gradle/gradle.properties from an init script distributed inside a custom gradle wrapper.

### ~/.gradle/gradle.properties

```
companyLogin=test
```

### ~/.gradle/wrapper/dists/.../companyLoginCheck.gradle

```
println "Company Username: " + companyLogin
```

This fails: "Could not find property 'companyLogin' on build.

### projectRoot/buld.gradle

```
task printCompanyLogin {
    println "Company Username: " + companyLogin
}
```

This works fine (I have to comment out the init script one)

I am making sure I execute with $gradlew .

I've also tried putting companyLogin=test in the project root gradle.properties without success.  Is this intentional behavior of Gradle?  I don't recall seeing it in the manual, but I've not had as much time with Gradle in the last 6 months or so as I'd like.

Anyone have any suggestions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The issue was one of system properties vs project properties.

Init scripts run before the project is created, and therefor cannot access project properties.

Situation resolved with the following settings:

### ~/.gradle/gradle.properties

```
systemProp.company.login=test
```

### ~/.gradle/wrapper/dists/.../companyLoginCheck.gradle

```
final companyLogin = System.properties["company.login"]
```